# network: download with one device, upload with other device

Tags: networking, fedora

Situation: I have an ethernet connection that is fast in upload; and I have a wifi connection that is fast in download. In other words: ethernet download is slower than wifi download. Both connections get me to the same gateway/IP Address.

I run Fedora 34.

Can I define a download route via one device (wifi) and an upload route via another device (eth)?

Caveat: I searched for a bit, and I guess I miss some language to formulate the question precisely. I invite comments that help me revise the question.

Answer (score 2):

For all traffic in general, No.. (There are scenarios where asymmetric routing could be made possible, but no).

But there are corner cases where you may be able to achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

You can manipulate your computer's routing table to direct the traffic flow in certain directions. For instance, if your Default-gw is pointing to your Eth-interface, and you want to download a large file from a specific server via the Wifi-interface, you could set a static route towards the IP address of your file server to point to the exit router on the Wifi-interface. Traffic in both directions will go through the Wifi-interface when communicating to the server. All other traffic will flow through the Eth-if.

Lots of blogs describe how to set routes in Linux. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ip-route-add-network-command-for-linux-explained/ could be a good start.

If your interfaces are both connected to the same subnet, you need to specify which interface to egress from:

```
ip route add <dest-ip>/32 via <gw-ip> dev <your interface>
```

Note: Do not try this on a remote host if you are not absolutely confident about what you are doing. You may end up cutting your access to the server or isolate the server itself.